# Extending abstract Typescript class and interface with return type of itself

Tags: typescript

Consider the following base interface and abstract class:

```
export interface IPersonViewModel {
    name: string;

    setName(value: string): IPersonViewModel;
}

export abstract class PersonViewModel implements IPersonViewModel {
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public name: string;

    public setName(value: string): IPersonViewModel {
        const vm = { ...this, name: value };
        return vm;
    }
}
```

Now consider the following derived class and interface:

```
export interface IEmployeeViewModel extends IPersonViewModel {
    role: string;
}

export class EmployeeViewModel extends PersonViewModel implements IEmployeeViewModel {
    constructor(role: string, name: string) {
        super(name);
        this.role = role;
    }
    public role: string;

    public setRole(value: string): IEmployeeViewModel {
        const vm = { ...this, role: value };
        return vm;
    }
}
```

If setName is used on an instance of IEmployeeViewModel the return type is IPersonViewModel. Is there any way to use generics or some other methodology such that the return type of the base interface function is the same as the implemented interface i.e. IEmployeeViewModel.setName returns IEmployeeViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need generics.  All that you need is the polymorhic `this` type.  Use `this` as the return type in both the `interface` and the classes.

```
export interface IPersonViewModel {
    name: string;

    setName(value: string): this;
}
```

```
public setName(value: string): this {
...
```

Now you are telling TypeScript that the returned type of `setName` should match the type of the original object.

```
const employee = new EmployeeViewModel('someRole', 'someName');
// renamed has type EmployeeViewModel
const renamed = employee.setName('Bob');
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/Nn496W)

---

You might use generics if you were interacting with an implementation of `IPersonViewModel` in a situation where you didn't know what specific implementation you were dealing with.

This sort of function is fine, because the implementation doesn't matter.  All `IPersonViewModel` objects have a `name` and a `setName`.

```
const nameModifyFn = (object: IPersonViewModel): string => {
    return object.setName('new name').name;
}
```

But here you could use a generic so that the return type matches the original type.

```
const nameModifyFn = <T extends IPersonViewModel>(object: T): T => {
    return object.setName('new name');
}
```