# (typescript) extending class type is not assignable to base class type

Tags: typescript, inheritance, extends

I am pretty new to typescript. I want to create a map, that stores a class reference under the name `component`. It should allow any classes that extend the abstract class `Component`. I dont want to store a reference to a class instance but rather to the class itself, so I could create a class instance by calling `new map.component()`. This however fails whenever the constructor of the extending class doesnt match the constructor of the `Component` class and I get the error message:

```
Type 'typeof Extending' is not assignable to type 'typeof Component'.
  Types of construct signatures are incompatible.
    Type 'new (r: number, parent?: Component | undefined) => Extending' is not assignable to type 'abstract new (identifier: string, parent?: Component | undefined) => Component'.
      Types of parameters 'r' and 'identifier' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

```
abstract class Component {
    protected _identifier: string;
    protected _parent: Component | undefined;

    protected constructor(identifier: string, parent?: Component) {
        this._identifier = identifier;
        this._parent = parent;
    }
}

class Extending extends Component {
    constructor(parent?: Component) {
        super("hi", parent);
    }
}

type map = {
    component: typeof Component
}

let m: map = {
    component: Extending // <---  this is where the error occurs, component is underlined
}
```

Comment: That doesnt make sense to me. I supply the constructor of the abstract class with a string value in `super(`, why would I need to match the signature if I provide a value directly and not over the constructor of the extending class?

Comment: Of course the arguments of the super call must match the constructor of the Component class, but why would I need to have matching constructor signaturs? I mean I cant supply any other arguments in the `Extending` class, not even `constructor(r: number, identifier: string, parent?: Component)` works.

Comment: @JaredSmith your example also doesnt work with additional constructor args in class B. This defeats the whole purpose of inheritance if I cant supply additional args. [tsplayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggg3gKAQVEhngRAC4ESBLAOwHMBuApAezpIFd42oAKAA5cQyGrCJU6XALYgAplACUuAL551eFGgwAhBPIAeEeXQAmGbPkIgEAXgQAiAGaOWhWB268Bw0eIQoKVkFKAAaBD8xCWBguUUVa0JqLkFFfmAldwR1TQgATzSEGWBBe1xWTxlBDlMIKgK0tmcsDTw8ZHlEGSoSsockqpq6OqpdNvagA)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69327960/extending-abstract-typescript-class-and-interface-with-return-type-of-itself. You would expect that the class `EmployeeViewModel` is also of type `PersonViewModel` as it extends that class. However this is not the case because `EmployeeViewModel` has an additional constructor argument `role`. This cant be intended. The whole point of inheritance is that extending classes inherit the properties/methods etc from the base class, but also have additional properties/methods.

Comment: Class constructors are one of the few places in TypeScript where class hierarchies can fail to be type hierarchies (which causes interesting issues like [ms/TS#3841](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841)), specifically because of differences in constructor arguments.  But if you want to write `new map.component()` then the `component` property should be of type `new () => Component` and not `typeof Component`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WyqKbW); does that meet your needs and address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: This works perfectly and applies exactly to my usecase. But it would be nice if you could explain to me why that workes, but `typeof Component` doesnt.

Comment: In general inheritance applies to objects of certain types, not the types themselves. Am I missing something?

Comment: The comments above explain why `typeof Component` doesn't work; a value of type `typeof Component` expects a constructor argument of type `string`, but `typeof Extending`  does not.  So `typeof Extending` is not assignable to  `typeof Component`.  I'm happy to go into detail in my answer but the explanation isn't going to be much different from what's already here.  The static side of class hierarchies doesn't necessarily form a type hierarchy, specifically to allow subclasses to have differing constructor arguments.  Anyway I'll write up an answer when I get the chance.

Comment: @apokryfos I am used to java where any instance of a class B that extends A is a type of B, but also of A. That means that both `B instance = new B()` and `À instance = new B()` is valid. In typescript I thought that this would also be the case and also for types, not only for the objects instead. but as it seems this is not the case.

Comment: But here you're talking about `new B` which matches the type of both A and B. In your Typescript example there is no `new` you are referring to the type itself

Comment: @apokryfos exactly, I thought that class inheritance also applies to types. But as jcalz said this is not the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Ideally*, wherever you have `X extends Y`, it would mean that `X` should be [substitutable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) for `Y`.  So if you have `interface Foo extends Bar` then you can use a `Foo` wherever a `Bar` is needed... interface extension should imply subtyping.  Or if you have `class Baz extends Qux` then you can use a `Baz` instance wherever a `Qux` instance is needed... class extension should imply instance subtyping.  And, ideally, you would also be able to use the static `Baz` value itself wherever the static `Qux` value is needed... class extension should imply static subtyping. And to a large extent this does happen: both the instance side and the static side of a class is inherited by its subclasses; but there are exceptions.

You've just run into the exception in which the [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) of [a subclass](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#extends-clauses) is not required to be assignable to that of its base class.  It's a very useful feature of JavaScript and therefore supported by TypeScript... but unfortunately this can prevent the static side of a class hierarchy from being a type hierarchy:

```
class Baz {
  constructor(x: string) { }
  static v: number = 10;
  w: string = "abc"
}

class Qux extends Baz {
  constructor(x: number) {
    super(x.toFixed(1))
  }
}
```

Here, the type named `Qux` (the instance side) is assignable to the type named `Baz`.  And, *except for the construct signature itself*, the value named `Qux` (the static side) is assignable to the type of the value named `Baz`.  That is, both of them have a `v` property of type `number`:

```
console.log(Qux.v.toFixed(1)) // 10.0
```

But the `Baz` constructor expects a `string`, and if you substitute the `Qux` constructor for `Baz` and try to construct it like `Baz`, you'll pass a `string` into something that expects a `number` and there will be a runtime error.  So TypeScript prevents you from assigning the constructor type of a subclass to the constructor type of a superclass unless their construct signatures are compatible:

```
let ctor: typeof Baz;
ctor = Baz; // okay
ctor = Qux; // error

class Quux extends Qux {
  constructor(x: string) {
    super(x.length);
  }
}
ctor = Quux; // okay,
```

This exception is responsible for a certain amount of weirdness in TypeScript; for example, the `constructor` property of a class instance is not strongly typed; the compiler only sees it as `Function`.  So the type of `(new Baz()).constructor` is seen as `Function` instead of `typeof Baz`.  That's the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#3841](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841). If it *were* `typeof Baz`, then the instance side of classes could *also* fail to form a type hierarchy, and that would just be too much to handle.

---

*Anyway*, you don't really *want* the type of `component` to be `typeof Component`.  Even if the subclass didn't change the constructor argument types, your base class is [`abstract`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#abstract-classes-and-members) and thus unconstructable.

What you want is for the `component` property to be a concrete (non-`abstract`) zero-arg constructor that produces a value assignable to `Component`.  So you should just use the appropriate construct signature directly and ignore `typeof Component` entirely:

```
type MyMap = {
  component: new () => Component 
}

let m: MyMap = {
  component: Extending // okay
}
```

Now you can write `new m.component();` as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgwgewLYAdsA7AUyMQG8AoBBfKbCE+EgEwQH0BLVsiLgGZcSUAFwJIULkQDmAbhp0GTFuw75gUPuJwFifBAB8EAVyK8hpVgsX1GzJu1jFJJ+NigAKHn0HCxEtDSMgA0dJp8APw6eISk5ACUCNS0tBAAFlxgAHTcvOR+IggAvAg+BUIiCqkIGVm5GlrkJeFNENUIAL5U3VQoaBgAogAeTObBCCSjZKwYunEGKUgu0G4QHp6NUTF68RBJS7RgJvgingBEmedhW4kd3b0QAJ6nCACyT2-A+C1LzrvaBCkADuCE8SWKAD4sLF9OQelQqMgSIhcOIPl8fqU-rC9uIRmNWMEEVQQQhcNl-gtyOCbIi+qh0AgAELAABeyUUziIrncXmG4kkwQOXUUkGA-FgCAAbuIiCZcCAiqUAIwABg6wMFQVkLXOoFg5xJ-SZAEUTMNJtNzBhWRycTzVnzPAKgQqlVADoojiczsNsusAGJcYZsTwqhIJRQPRHcsDYZHZZDYGSec3+6UB7DB0OscORhAAekLCHV2TViORiD54mep2wAhZ7IUfJadrkRZL2AA1sAnn11lAWumO8XJlAGFBY4yMOaLVbCbP5w7eYOXdqpLIvTVjqd+UmyDIMgl7gjW6U58NR13e08gA)